# django Middleware to handle crossxhr requests is not working

Tags: python, django

I wrote a middleware for Django 2.1 to handle cross-domain XHR requests, but it's not working, in fact, it's not even getting called for requests or response and does n't print anything.

**Settings.py**

```
XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = "*"

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'app_name.middleware.crossdomainxhr.XsSharing',
]
```

**crossdomainxhr.py**

```
import logging
from django import http
from django.conf import settings

try:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
except AttributeError:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = '*'

try:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS
except AttributeError:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE']

try:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS
except:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS = ['Content-Type', '*']

try:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS = 
        settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS
except AttributeError:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS = 'true'


class XsSharing:
    """
    This middleware allows cross-domain XHR using the html5 postMessage 
    API.
    """
    **EDIT**
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        print('Hi, I am middleware')
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        print('hello')
        self.process_request(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response = self.process_response(request, response)
        return response
    def process_request(self, request):
        print('calling request section')
        if 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD' in request.META:
            response = http.HttpResponse()
            response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 
            XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
                response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 
                    ",".join(XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS)
                response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 
                    ",".join(XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS)
                response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 
                    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS
        return response

    return None

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        print('calling response')
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 
            XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 
            ",".join(XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 
            ",".join(XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 
            XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS

    return response
```

Problem is if I call some URL of my app from another Django app then the request get blocked, Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES was deprecated in Django 1.10 and removed in Django 2.0. You should use the MIDDLEWARE setting and a [new-style middleware class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/).

Comment: edited the question as per latest doc, but still not working can you again have a look please

Comment: Did you update the setting name? Does it print any of your debugging messages?

Comment: No it did n't print anything, my setting name will be ```'app_name.middleware.crossdomainxhr.XsSharing'```. right?

MIddleware is the directory name under my app folder

Comment: I meant, did you change the name of the setting from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to MIDDLEWARE?